# Where did my proof of Eberlein–Smulyan Theorem go wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification

Eberlein–Smulyan Theorem:

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $B$ the closed unit ball in $X$. The
> followings are equivalent:
>
> 1. $X$ is reflexive
> 2. $B$ is weakly compact
> 3. $B$ is weak sequentially compact

I have no problem with $ (1) \iff (2) $ and $ (1) \implies (3) $. It remains to prove $ (3) \implies (1) $. I have come up with the following proof:

> Claim: If $B$ is weak sequentially compact, then $X$ is reflexive.

**Proof:**

Let $ J_X : X \to X^{**}, x \mapsto \hat{x} $ be the canonical embedding given by $ \hat{x}(f) = f(x), f \in X^* $. By Goldstine theorem, the weak$^*$ closure of $ J_X(B) $ is the closed unit ball $ B^{**} $ in $ X^{**} $.

Let $ \psi \in B^{**} $. Then there exists a sequence $ (x_n) $ in $B$ such that $ (\hat{x_n}) $ converges weak$^*$ to $\psi$, so

$$ f(x_n) = \psi(f) \quad \text{for all } f \in X^* $$

On the other hand, $B$ is weak sequentially compact by the assumption. Thus, $ (x_n) $ has a subsequence $ (x_{n_k}) $ that converges weakly to a point $x \in B$, so

$$ f(x_{n_k}) = f(x) \quad \text{for all } f \in X^* $$

By uniqueness of limits, we have

$$ \psi(f) = f(x) \quad \text{for all } f \in X^* $$

This implies $ \psi = \hat{x} $. In conclusion $ J_X(B) = B^{**} $, so $X$ is reflexive.

**Problem:**

I am skeptical of my proof because it seems unbelievebly easy, whereas my textbook has provided a long technical proof. Can you help me find out where my proof went wrong?

Comment: Being in the weak$^\ast$ closure of $J_X(B)$ does *not* give you a sequence necessarily in a general space, just a net (a generalised sequence), unless you know that $B^{\ast\ast}$ is a so-called Fréchet-Urysohn space.. And you cannot just assume that it is... And without a sequence you cannot apply sequential compactness.

Comment: Your proof works if  $X^*$ is separable, since then the closed unit ball of $X^{**}$ is metrizable wrt the weak-star topology. Hence,  you can extract a weak-star convergent subsequence.